# Having trouble getting checkboxes to update after value change

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a writable store called $selectedDates which is an array of strings.  When each element on a page is checked it should add its date string to the array.  If its unchecked it should remove it. The array/store gets updated fine, but the element doesn't re-render to show the change. Shouldn't the below be reactive once $selectedDates changes?

```
<script>
    import {selectedDates} from "$lib/stores"

    let checked: boolean
    $: checked = $selectedDates.includes(datez(day.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))

    function handleClick(e: Event) {
        console.log("got click", $selectedDates)
        if (!$selectedDates.includes(datez(day.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))) {
            selectedDates.update((dates) => [...dates, datez(day.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")])
        } else {
            selectedDates.update((dates) => dates.filter((date) => date !== datez(day.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")))
        }
        console.log("after click update", $selectedDates)
    }
</script>
```

```
<input bind:checked on:click|preventDefault={handleClick} type="checkbox" style="font-size: medium;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected behaviour is probably due to the binding of `checked` to a reactive variable. You could change the logic by binding to the normal variable and react to its value change like this
[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5df2a7c2c25d4ac1a54670cb9fccd89c?version=3.50.0)

```
<script>
    import {writable} from 'svelte/store'
    export const selectedDates = writable([])

    const specialDate = "2023-01-09"

    let checked
    
    $: if(checked){
        $selectedDates =  [...$selectedDates, specialDate]
    }else {
        $selectedDates =  $selectedDates.filter((date) => date !== specialDate)
    }
    
    $: console.log('checked', checked, 'selectedDates', $selectedDates)

</script>

<input bind:checked type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: I tried this but it started an endless loop and locked up the page.  I didn't post all the code because there's so much I didn't think was relevant.  There's a lot going on with this page - like around 30 charts being rendered, etc.  I found a solution but I'm not sure why it works.  Will post on a minute.  Thanks for your help just the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I got it to work, though I have no idea why.  (I found this code on a REPL).

EDIT1: Removed "bind"

```
    let checked: boolean
        selectedDates.subscribe((dates) => {
        checked = dates.includes(datez(day.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
    })
    
    function handleClick(e: Event) {
        if (!$selectedDates.includes(datez(day.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))) {
            selectedDates.update((dates) => [...dates, datez(day.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")])
        } else {
            selectedDates.update((dates) => dates.filter((date) => date !== datez(day.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")))
        }
        let target = e.target as HTMLInputElement
        setTimeout(() => (target.checked = checked), 0)
       
    }
```

```
<input {checked} on:click|preventDefault={handleClick} type="checkbox" style="font-size: medium;" />
```

Comment: There's really no sense in adding a double-way binding (which is what `bind:checked` does) if you're going to handle click events programatically and set `checked` through that handler. It just adds confusion and potential conflicts. You'd be better off just having a `checked={checked}` attribute (or simply `{checked}` for brevity).

Comment: Thanks and I agree. That's originally how I had it but accidentally left bind after doing some experimenting.